# Visual C#: how to LaunchChildProcess with a command line argument

Tags: windows-services, command-line-arguments, launch

I am executing a program from inside a service like this:

```
CreateProcessAsUserWrapper.LaunchChildProcess("C:\\someDirectory\\notify.exe 1");
```

It works fine with just notify.exe, but it doesn't work when I attempt to send the parameter 1.  I get no error or notification, just nothing happens.

The code for CreateProcessAsUserWrapper can be found here:
http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/FBB7577C/7A33AB93

I added a ChildProcArg to try to get it to work

```
public static void LaunchChildProcess(string ChildProcName, string ChildProcArg)
{
```

...

```
bool ChildProcStarted = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken,             // Token of the logged-on user.
    ChildProcName,      // Name of the process to be started.
    ChildProcArg,       // Any command line arguments to be passed.
    IntPtr.Zero,        // Default Process' attributes.
    IntPtr.Zero,        // Default Thread's attributes.
    false,              // Does NOT inherit parent's handles.
    0,                  // No any specific creation flag.
    null,               // Default environment path.
    null,               // Default current directory.
    ref tStartUpInfo,   // Process Startup Info.
    out tProcessInfo    // Process information to be returned.
    );
```

so when I call it, it now looks like this:

```
CreateProcessAsUserWrapper.LaunchChildProcess("C:\\someDirectory\\notify.exe", "1");
```

... but it is still not passing the argument.  At least the program runs now, but the argument is ignored.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
For future searchers I will include answer here.
The full program and path must be provided along with the argument.
So I just added this:

```
ChildProcArg = ChildProcName + " " + ChildProcArg;
```

... just above this ...

```
bool ChildProcStarted = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken,             // Token of the logged-on user.
    ChildProcName,      // Name of the process to be started.
    ChildProcArg,       // Any command line arguments to be passed.
```